# import contacts from yahoo using PHP

Tags: php, ssl, oauth

I am in a situation where I have to import contacts from Yahoo using PHP and after searching the web I got the following code done:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/Yahoo.inc';

//for converting xml to array
function XmltoArray($xml) {
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($xml), TRUE);

        foreach ( array_slice($array, 0) as $key => $value ) {
            if ( empty($value) ) $array[$key] = NULL;
            elseif ( is_array($value) ) $array[$key] = XmltoArray($value);
        }

        return $array;
    }

// debug settings
//error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE); # do not show notices as library is php4 compatable
//ini_set('display_errors', true);
YahooLogger::setDebug(true);
YahooLogger::setDebugDestination('LOG');

// use memcache to store oauth credentials via php native sessions
//ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
//session_save_path('/tmp/');
session_start();

// Make sure you obtain application keys before continuing by visiting:
// https://developer.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html

define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY', '****');
define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET', '*********');
define('OAUTH_DOMAIN', '****');
define('OAUTH_APP_ID', '****');

if(array_key_exists("logout", $_GET)) {
  // if a session exists and the logout flag is detected
  // clear the session tokens and reload the page.
  YahooSession::clearSession();
  header("Location: index.php");
}

// check for the existance of a session.
// this will determine if we need to show a pop-up and fetch the auth url,
// or fetch the user's social data.
$hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

if($hasSession == FALSE) {
  // create the callback url,
  $callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";
$sessionStore = new NativeSessionStore();
  // pass the credentials to get an auth url.
  // this URL will be used for the pop-up.
  $auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback, $sessionStore);



}
else {
  // pass the credentials to initiate a session
  $session = YahooSession::requireSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);

  // if the in_popup flag is detected,
  // the pop-up has loaded the callback_url and we can close this window.
  if(array_key_exists("in_popup", $_GET)) {
    close_popup();
    exit;
  }

  // if a session is initialized, fetch the user's profile information
  if($session) {
    // Get the currently sessioned user.
    $user = $session->getSessionedUser();

    // Load the profile for the current user.
    $profile = $user->getProfile();
    $profile_contacts=XmltoArray($user->getContactSync());
   $contacts=array();
   foreach($profile_contacts['contactsync']['contacts'] as $key=>$profileContact){
       foreach($profileContact['fields'] as $contact){
          $contacts[$key][$contact['type']]=$contact['value'];
       }
   }
  // echo "<pre/>";
  // print_r($contacts);exit;

  }
}
//echo "<pre />";
//print_r($_SESSION);exit;
/**
 * Helper method to close the pop-up window via javascript.
 */
function close_popup() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.close();
</script>
<?php
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Get the contact list from Yahoo</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.yh_frnds{
    list-style:none;
}
.yh_frnds li{
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
.frnd_list{
    margin-top:-25px;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.fb_frnds a{
        text-decoration:none;
         background: #333;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#D95858'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#D95858)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #333,  #D95858)/* for firefox 3.6+ */ ;
    color: #FFFFFF;
        float: right;
        font: bold 13px arial;
        margin-right:110px ;


}
</style>

    <!-- Combo-handled YUI JS files: -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popupmanager.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if($hasSession == FALSE) { 
        // if a session does not exist, output the
        // login / share button linked to the auth_url.
        ?>
       <a href="<?php echo $auth_url; ?>" id="yloginLink"><img src="yahoo-oauth-connect.png" style="width:150px;margin-left: 350px;" title="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" alt="Get the contact list from Yahoo-Idiot Minds" /></a>
    <?php  }
      else if($hasSession && $profile) {  

        // if a session does exist and the profile data was
        // fetched without error, print out a simple usercard.
       ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $profile->image->imageUrl; ?>" style="width:10%;" />
      <h2>Hi <a href="<?php echo $profile->profileUrl; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $profile->nickname; ?></a>
      </h2>

<?php
        if($profile->status->message != "") {
          $statusDate = date('F j, y, g:i a', strtotime($profile->status->lastStatusModified));
          echo sprintf("<p><strong>&#8220;</strong>%s<strong>&#8221;</strong> on %s</p>", $profile->status->message, $statusDate);
        }

        echo "<p><a href=\"?logout\">Logout</a></p>"; ?>

        <ul  class="yh_frnds">
<?php
    foreach($contacts as $user_friend){

     if(isset($user_friend['email'])){
?>
<li ><img src="yahoo1.png" width="30" height="30"/>
<div  class="frnd_list"><strong><?php echo $user_friend['name']['givenName']; ?></strong><br /><?php echo $user_friend['email'];?></div>
</li>

<?php }
 }  ?>
</ul>
 <?php     }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var Event = YAHOO.util.Event;
      var _gel = function(el) {return document.getElementById(el)};

      function handleDOMReady() {
        if(_gel("yloginLink")) {
          Event.addListener("yloginLink", "click", handleLoginClick);
        }
      }

      function handleLoginClick(event) {
        // block the url from opening like normal
        Event.preventDefault(event);

        // open pop-up using the auth_url
        var auth_url = _gel("yloginLink").href;
        PopupManager.open(auth_url,600,435);
      }

      Event.onDOMReady(handleDOMReady);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

While loading this page am getting the following error:

> ERROR - Error making libcurl
>   request(https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token): SSL
>   certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate ERROR -
>   OAuth call to get request token failed ERROR - Failed to create
>   request token

I am simply clueless on how to resolve this...I have done this with GMail and Facebook but in Yahoo am getting this error. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: can anyone please enlighten the issue...am really struggling